# Prob. 9, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: If $f^\prime(x)$ exists for $x\neq 0$, $f$ is continuous at $0$, and $f^\prime(x)\to 3$ as $x\to 0$, then ...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Here is Prob. 9, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Let $f$ be a continuous real function on $\mathbb{R}^1$, of which it is known that $f^\prime(x)$ exists for all $x \neq 0$ and that $f^\prime(x) \to 3$ as $x \to 0$. Does it follows that $f^\prime(0)$ exists?

My effort:

> For any $x \neq 0$, the function $f$ is continuous on the interval 
>   $$ \left[\  \min \left\{ 0, x \right\}, \max \left\{ 0, x \right\} \ \right] $$
>   and is differentiable on the segment 
>   $$ \left( \  \min \left\{ 0, x \right\}, \max \left\{ 0, x \right\} \ \right). $$
>   So by the Mean Value Theorem we can find a point 
>   $$p \in  \left( \  \min \left\{ 0, x \right\}, \max \left\{ 0, x \right\} \ \right) $$
>   such that 
>   $$\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = f^\prime(p).$$ 
>   Now as $x \to 0$, $p \to 0$ also. Therefore we can conclude that 
>   $$ f^\prime(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{p \to 0} f^\prime(p) = 3.$$
>   So $f^\prime(0)$ exists indeed!

Is my reasoning correct? If so, have I arrived at the correct conclusion as well? If not, then where lies the pitfall?

Comment: Looks good to me.  The only style point I would make is that it will read cleaner if you assume $x>0$ first.  Then you can write $[0,x]$ and $(0,x)$ for all the intervals.  The conclusion is that $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = 3$.  For the case $x<0$, you can either write the intervals the other way, or just say “The case $x<0$ is treated similarly.”

Comment: maybe a line to make it clear why the mean value theorem holds as you require, without differentiability at 0. otherwise there is a faint whiff of circular argument?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang thank you for your valuable comment. Is my proof rigorous enough for Rudin's level?

Comment: @DavidHolden is my proof rigorous enough for Rudin?

Comment: Like I said, looks good to me.  If this were submitted by a student of mine I would give it full marks.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang so nice of you!! Which texts are followed for the very first analysis and topology courses at your department?

Comment: Depends on the instructor.